# Curiosity about DNS using dig command

Tags: dns, ip, web, cname, dig

I am analyzing the DNS section for the website imgur.com. My doubt is that when I run "dig imgur.com" dig only returns an IP address, if I run again the same command dig returns another IP address or sometimes the same.

Another question:
By using dig www.imgur.com get a CNAME to another domain, is this normal?, Can someone explain to me?

Comment: Load balancing.

Comment: @DavidPostill, but why ? i see only one, i would like to see all IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using dig www.imgur.com get a CNAME to another domain

That "another domain" is the *content distribution network* (CDN) used by Imgur –
 essentially a hosting provider which specializes in caching static data (videos, cat gifs) all around the world, ideally as close as possible to the visitors.

By delegating this task to a CDN, Imgur only needs to worry about hosting the original data in a single datacenter or two, rather than everywhere.

> if I run again the same command dig returns another IP address or sometimes the same

CDNs use various methods of load-balancing and *do not need* to list all IP addresses at once in the DNS reply.

- A single IP address can point to a load-balancer backed by multiple actual hosting servers.
- A single IP address may exist in *several locations* using anycast. Your packets always go to whichever location your ISP considers "nearest".
- Fastly's DNS server generates the replies dynamically, so that it can avoid giving you addresses of overloaded servers.
- Many CDNs also use "GeoDNS" – that is, they give you the IP address of the *closest* server, so you'd always get different results in Europe from USA anyway.

> i would like to see all IP address

`dig` just shows the data that Fastly is giving you, and does not have a special trick to return "all" addresses.

Remember that the addresses are usually *shared* across all customers of that CDN, so blocking the entire range would result in blocking *quite a few* websites.